# How to write a hyperlink to notepad

Tags: python-3.x, hyperlink, notepad

Hi i have written this code and do not know what i am doing wrong when trying to add a hyperlink to a notepad document. Do anyone know what i am doing wrong? If you can it would be very helpful to me.

Here is my code:

```
import time
```

while True:

```
print('What is the name of the product?')
productName = input()
print('When does it go out of date?')
productDate = input()
print('What is the barcode? (This is optional)')
barcode = input()
print('Where did you get it from?')
productPlace = input()
print('**************************')
time.sleep(0.3)

if productPlace == 'Asda':
    purchaseProduct = 'https://groceries.asda.com/search/'+barcode 

class_file=open('Products','a')
class_file.write('The product is:')
class_file.write(productName)
class_file.write('The product goes out of date on the:')
class_file.write(productDate)
class_file.write("\n")
class_file.write('The barcode is:')
class_file.write(barcode)
class_file.write('\n')
class_file.write('place bought is:')
class_file.write(productPlace)
class_file.write('\n')
class_file.write('To buy this again go to:')
class_file.write_url(str(purchaseProduct))
class_file.write("**********************")
class_file.close()
```

Comment: Are you wanting a link that you could click on to take you to the web page? If so, this is not possible with notepad. The best you can do is a URL that can be copied and pasted into a web browser.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. That is what i wanted to do so thanks for confirming that with me. By any chance is there any way by doing it with Excel.

Comment: Yes there is. Personally, I think it is easier to use C# when working with excel and there are a lot of tutorials online about how to do that. There are also python libraries for working with excel as well. See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp